# array_multisort() and Objects - Warning "Array sizes are inconsistent"

Tags: php

I am a bit curious as to why the following throws a warning.

```
$obj->data = array(...); // note there are values stored (size 607)

var_dump(sizeof($obj->data)); // 607

array_multisort(
    array_column($obj->data , 'col1'), SORT_ASC,
    array_column($obj->data , 'col2'), SORT_ASC,
    array_column($obj->data , 'col3'), SORT_ASC, 
$obj->data 
);

var_dump(sizeof($obj->data)); // 607
```

The warning I receive states

> Warning: array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent

Can someone give me a bit more information than the warning?

Comment: Are you array since the same ?

Comment: @Nicolas they should be. The sizes before and after (with warning) are both `607`

Comment: @Newb4YouBB counting the main array doesn't mean each array it contains have the same number of element, nor always have the column your are extracting. Meaning the count you are doing here is not relevant in your debug, the problem is in the results of `array_column()` calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have different sizes among the arrays you pass as variables to the function:

```
array_multisort(
    array_column($obj->data , 'col1'), SORT_ASC,
    array_column($obj->data , 'col2'), SORT_ASC,
    array_column($obj->data , 'col3'), SORT_ASC, 
    $obj->data 
);
```

Probably `array_column($obj->data , 'col1')` (or col2 or col3) has less elements than `$obj->data`

For example:

```
$ar = array(
       array(1,2),
       array(2,1)
);
array_multisort($ar[0], $ar[1]);
```

Doesn't throw this warning, but

```
$ar = array(
       array(1,2,3),
       array(2,1)
);
array_multisort($ar[0], $ar[1]);
```

Will do.

Comment: Im going to accept this because it helped me take a closer look at my actual columns. I mistakenly titled `col1` when it should have been `col_1`. Thank you

Comment: most concise explanation of this error from all the search results returned on Stack Overflow